# Ошибка десериализации простейшего json

Tags: c#, json

Есть `json`. Пытаюсь через `Newtonsoftjson` привести его к классу. Выдает ошибку. Вроде все делаю как раньше. Не пойму в чем ошибка

```
var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json).Property1.Select(x=>x.value).ToList();

public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string firm { get; set; }
}

[
    {
        "value": "CL",
        "label": "CL",
        "firm": "ACURA"
    },
    {
        "value": "CSX",
        "label": "CSX",
        "firm": "ACURA"
    }
]
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Rootobject' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы же хотите получить в результате объект типа `Rootobject`.
Вот такой JSON, соответствующий структуре этого класса, десериализуется:

```
{ "Property1": [
    {
        "value": "CL",
        "label": "CL",
        "firm": "ACURA"
    },
    {
        "value": "CSX",
        "label": "CSX",
        "firm": "ACURA"
    }
]}
```

Comment: ну так json  с сервера приходит, мне выбирать не приходится

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>`